# How to delimit max event listeners in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm making an app which opens my university's website in another windows ( separate from the main window ) and downloads the study material from it. I'm using electron to build the app and puppeteer to automate the task. I've used puppeteer-in-electron for the same.

I want to know how to set the max event listeners on the window where I open the website to fix this error:

[image]

Because my program is only downloading 6 of the 14 slides.

I tried using `process.setMaxListeners(0)` in the main.js to no avail.